# How to recombine multipart zip files in python. each zip file contains a block of a large binary file

Tags: python, file, binary, zip, multipart

I have a large binary file which have been split into many zip files. i want to recombine these zip files to get my entire bianry file before launch my process

Comment: You have to open a single output file (in binary mode) and then sequentially read, unzip, and write the data from each zip file into it. It's important to process them in the right order, of course, so hopefully there's some way for you to figure that out.

Comment: Thanks you very much, i will try it and come back to you